# Botium Box CE Playground access?

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm using Botium Box CE from Docker, and until recently it had Playground access through the Botium Box URL, e.g.

> "https://botiumbox.mydomain.com/playground"

That disappeared in 1.7.4.  Playground can still be accessed through the Prisma service, but I keep getting "Project not found", which means I'm getting the default@default behavior for not using the right URL.  The "[Launching the GraphQL Playground](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/35553291/Using+the+Botium+Box+GraphQL+API#Launching-the-GraphQL-Playground)" documentation entry hasn't changed. What is the correct way to access Playground?

Comment: What url appears in the playground ?

Comment: http://localhost:4466/?APIKEY=REDACTED.  Port 4466 on localhost is forwarded to port 4466 of the prisma service in the K8s cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this is a bug. We already fixed it, and it will be included in the September release.